# Variable path issue : conda command not found

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

After installing Anaconda correctly. I wanted after finishing the installation to do the following. I forget to do it while installing anaconda:

**I added at the end of file**

export PATH="/root/anaconda3/bin"

**but I still get**

conda --version
conda command not found

Comment: gotta restart your terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you use ZSH or another Unix shell, copy to your .zshrc

```
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
```